# Fill in a matrix using another one with the same amount of row but different amount of columns

Tags: python, numpy

I have one empty matrix A

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

and I have another non empty matrix B

```
1 2
3 4
```

I want to put, for example, the first column of B into the first column of A, second column of B into the third column of A, like so

```
1 0 2
3 0 4
```

The idea is that I want to be able to match one column of B into A.

How can I achieve this using numpy and fancy indexing?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
b= np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
a.T[0]=b.T[0]
a.T[2]=b.T[1]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[1 0 2]
 [3 0 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.zeros((2, 3))
>>> B = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
>>> A[:, 0] = B[:, 0]
>>> A[:, 2] = B[:, 1]
>>> A
array([[1., 0., 2.],
       [3., 0., 4.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
a=np.zeros((2,3))
b=np.array([1,2,3,4]).reshape((2,2))
a[:,0]=b[:,0]
a[:,2]=b[:,1]
```